# Using a readymade Template for django frontend

Tags: django, django-templates

I tried using a readymade HTML5 template for my Django Project and updated the static links and all but it fails to load the CSS and js and other static files too.

My folder structure :

**MyProject

```
apps
templates
    MyProject
static
    MyProject
        css
        js
        etc**
```

My Settings for static :

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")] 
TEMPLATES = [
...... 
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'), 
os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static') .
 ..... ]
```

I have tried

- using the collectstatic command.
- Adding STATICFILES_DIRS.
- Adding [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development) code snippet to urls.py

Trace from terminal:

```
[04/Apr/2020 13:04:51] "GET /static/css/owl.theme.default.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1814
[04/Apr/2020 13:04:51] "GET /static/css/animate.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1772
[04/Apr/2020 13:04:51] "GET /static/css/magnific-popup.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1793
[04/Apr/2020 13:04:51] "GET /static/css/aos.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1760
[04/Apr/2020 13:04:51] "GET /static/css/owl.carousel.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1799
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

collectstatic will collect static resources that you have placed in your individual apps and copy them to an app directory within the project static directory. So, if you have an app static directory like this:

```
my_app
    static
        my_app
            css
            js
            etc
```

your project static dir will look like this after collectstatic:

```
static
    my_app
        css
        js
        etc
```

You can also manually place static resources in the project static directory. This is a good place for your project wide css, js, and image files.

```
static
    css
    images
    js
```

From the 404 errors you posted, the server is looking for your css files in the static/css/ directory and you have your css directory inside the MyProject directory. Move your css directory out one level and place your css files there and it should work.

Comment: So assuming my project static is empty and I'm running `collectstatic` after writing an app, in that case, my Project static will be automatically filled with app static.

Answer (score 1):

```
static
    MyProject
        css
        js
```

Your Error:

```
"GET /static/css/owl.theme.default.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1814
```

according to your error server is looking your file in static folder and then in css while your files is in static/MyProject/css
so, update your code in your html file

```
{% static 'MyProject/css/owl.theme.default.min.css' %}
```